# Adding jQuery hover effect within a for loop doesn't work

Tags: jquery, for-loop, hover, jquery-hover

As the title says, i try to add a jquery hover effect to different a-tags within a for loop. The hover-effects are added but the hide-show-functionality inside seems to be wrong. i always get the selector for the last li-element.

Any help would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/pGgeW/1/

here's the code:

html:

```
<a id="o1" href="#">Show Text 1</a>
<a id="o2" href="#">Show Text 2</a>
<a id="o3" href="#">Show Text 3</a>
<a id="o4" href="#">Show Text 4</a>
<a id="o5" href="#">Show Text 5</a>

<ul class="subTxt">
    <li id="u1">Text 1</li>
    <li id="u2">Text 2</li>
    <li id="u3">Text 3</li>
    <li id="u4">Text 4</li>
    <li id="u5">Text 5</li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
/* Hide li's */
$("ul.subTxt").find("li").each(

function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

/* Add Hover-Events */
for (var a = 1; a < 6; a++) {
    var k = '#o' + a;
    var e = '#u' + a;
    $(k).hover(

    function() {
        $(e).show();
        $(this).append('<div id="hk" style="position: relative;float: right;">' + k + ' ' + e + '</div>');
    }, function() {
        $(e).hide();
        $(this).find('#hk').remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you've found my answer below helpful and it solves your problem, please click the checkbox to the left of it, marking it as the answer so that others may find it easily.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it to this:

```
/* Hide li's */
$("ul.subTxt li").hide();

$("a.hover").hover(function(){
    var n = this.id.replace("o","");
    $("#u"+n).show();
}, function() {
    var n = this.id.replace("o","");
    $("#u"+n).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/pGgeW/3/

Answer (score 1):

Please review this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pGgeW/9/

```
$("ul.subTxt").find("li").hide();

$("a").hover(function(e) {
    $($(this).attr('href')).toggle();
}).click(function() { return false; });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#u1">Show Text 1</a>
<a href="#u2">Show Text 2</a>
<a href="#u3">Show Text 3</a>
<a href="#u4">Show Text 4</a>
<a href="#u5">Show Text 5</a>

<ul class="subTxt">
    <li id="u1">Text 1</li>
    <li id="u2">Text 2</li>
    <li id="u3">Text 3</li>
    <li id="u4">Text 4</li>
    <li id="u5">Text 5</li>
</ul>
```

Couple notes:

1. jQuery has looping built in.  If you apply an operation like `.hide()`, it applies it to the entire collection.  If you write a `for` loop to iterate over a jQuery collection, you're doing it wrong.
2. Generally you'll want to use a technique which associates your anchor tag with the target it's acting upon.  Commonly this is done with the href attribute when the href isn't an external page and instead an internal reference (which uses the # sign).  You'll see that I used it as a reference to the associated LI ID.

Comment: This is also a very nice solution. Thx Adam

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `e` and `k` variables are global.  One option would be to wrap that code in a function.  This way `e` and `k` are local to that function.  Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/pGgeW/8/

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, i'll keep this in mind for future.